# R Shiny: Upload user uploaded file to AWS S3 server

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shiny

I am trying to directly upload a user's file upload to AWS S3 within r shiny.

If I run the following code in R, I can upload successfully:

```
library(aws.s3)

S3_Bucket_Name <- "example_S3_Bucket"
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "example_ID",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "example_Key",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "example_Region")


example_Table = #uploaded .csv    


put_object(file = charToRaw(toString(example_Table)), object = paste0("example_File",".csv"), bucket = S3_Bucket_Name)
```

How can I replicate this functionality within the following Shiny app?

```
library(shiny)
library(aws.s3)

S3_Bucket_Name <- "example_S3_Bucket"
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "example_ID",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "example_Key",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "example_Region")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("example_Table", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe(put_object(file = charToRaw(toString(input$example_Table)), object = paste0("example_File",".csv"), bucket = S3_Bucket_Name))
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your global and ui definitions above, the following server code should work:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$example_Table, { # when the fileInput field named example_Table is updated, trigger the put_object function defined below

    aws.s3::put_object(file = input$example_Table$datapath[1], # this provides the tmp location of uploaded file
                       object = input$example_Table$name[1], # assuming you want the name as uploaded with no additional prefix (can use paste for prefix)
                       bucket = S3_Bucket_Name, # using the same object name you defined in your example
                       multipart = TRUE # optional
                       )
  })
}
```

Observing the put_file function as illustrated in your original code won't work. The function is not part of your UI and will not change, therefore, no event would ever be triggered.

Instead you need to observe either your fileInput or some other input to trigger your put_object logic.

In order to make this work, you'll also need the temporary file location of the uploaded file within the session. This can be retrieved through the $datapath associated with your fileInput.

In this case you've named it "example_Table", so we can reference the first (only) datapath value using example_Table$datapath[1]. We can also use a similar pattern leveraging the $name value for the object argument in the put_object function as shown above.

More information about the values available from the fileInput ui element can be found in the "Server value" section of the documentation for the fileInput function: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input[["file"]], {
    
    csvpath <- input[["file"]][["datapath"]]
    csvname <- input[["file"]][["name"]]
    HR_roster <- rawToChar(get_object(csvpath, bucket = S3_Bucket_Name))
    put_object(file = charToRaw(toString(HR_roster)), object = csvname, bucket = S3_Bucket_Name)
    
  })
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Stéphane Laurent. I have edited the question slightly so as not to focus on ```get_object```. I am only aiming to upload a users local file direct to S3. I still can't quite get there. Thanks for your help.